# Mac terminal font sometime sharp sometime blurry?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to understand why Mac terminal font is not sharp.

Mac terminal most of the time shows up like this:

[image]

Rarely it shows up like this:

[image]

Much sharper. I want to make it so it is always like the second image here, the sharper version.

What could be causing the fond to be not as sharp like shown in the first image?

I am running macOS 12.0 Monterey.

And this is my General and Profiles tabs:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the *Antialias text* option in Terminal's Preference->Profiles. My guess is that you sometimes switch between the predefined *Basic* profile, which has the option enabled, and the *Homebrew* profile, which has it disabled.

In the Preferences *General* tab, you can setup the Terminal to use a non-default profile on startup. If you do so, but at the same time have new windows open with the default profile, you get a different profile for every Terminal window but the first, which may be why you see these differences.

Comment: So I looked at the other profiles and just for testing I unchecked the antialias text option on all. I then quit terminal and re-opened it. So far it's always been blurry. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @zumzum Strange. Well you can always try [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com) which also allows you to disable antialiasing. By the way, this is a non-retina-display, right? I can't really reproduce the issue since I can't see my pixels here…

Comment: yes, on external monitor. I'll check iTerm2. Thank you.

Comment: iTerm2 works great. deselecting Anti-aliased option makes text look sharp consistently. Wonder why terminal is not following the setting clearing unchecked in the default theme I have.

Comment: @zumzum Terminal always looks „good enough“ but most people don't go back after trying iTerm because of stuff like this. I can imagine this is some bug Apple is simply not aware of because nobody tests for non-retina displays…

Comment: yes, I don't think I'll go back. When you look at a terminal window for hours a day... things like that make a big difference.